# Execute JS code (using jQuery) with and without Turbolinks

Tags: jquery, turbolinks, turbolinks-5

I'd like to execute code (using jQuery) when the page is loading. I want it to work with AND without Turbolinks.

For Turbolinks, the code is the following :

```
document.addEventListener("turbolinks:load", function() {
  // ...
})
```

What have I to modify to make it work without Turbolinks too?

Thank you

Comment: Is `$(document).on("ready turbolinks:load", function () { [...] })` correct ?

Comment: The answer can be find here: https://forum.humancoders.com/t/executer-du-code-js-jquery-avec-et-sans-turbolinks/2200/2?u=camilleroux